# Is it possible to run a bash script in a sort of sandbox?

Tags: bash

Our product has a need to execute an unknown bash script on a delicate server in order to achieve a certain goal. This bash script is user-supplied. We are interested in ensuring that only specific commands are allowed, and that all other are not. Furthermore, we need to replace some commands with others.

So, for example, we would like to execute the script and allow the following commands:
echo
cat
awk

But not allow any other command (we don't want to supply a specific list here).

Furthermore, if the script contains the command cp we would like to capture it and redirect to a different command (which can be done using alias).

Any idea how this is done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a **chroot jail** containing only the commands you want the script to be able to run. You then run the script through a wrapper that calls `chroot` into the directory and then executes the script.

Answer (score 19):

There is no 100% safe short of running the script inside a virtual machine, which would presumably prevent the script from achieving its goal. But there are two features that may help you. If you're worried that the script was written by a malicious person, these features are not enough; but if you're only worried that the script may do bad things to your system because it was written by a careless programmer or with different objectives in mind, either of these two features provides a decent sandboxing environment.

- You can run a **restricted shell** by invoking bash as `bash -r`. I refer you to the bash manual for a detailed description; the basic idea is that the script cannot invoke commands that are not in `$PATH`, cannot change `$PATH`, cannot redirect to or from a file, and a few more restrictions. This is fairly simple to set up, but if the unknown script is too complicated for you to review, it's likely to use a lot of things that are forbidden in a restricted shell.
- You can set up a **chroot** jail. The idea is to set up a directory tree `/some/root` and run the script in an environment that believes that `/some/root` is the whole filesystem (`chroot` is short for change root). Once the directory tree is set up, run the script (copied to `/some/root/myscript`) as `chroot /some/root /bin/bash /myscript`. For example, you would set up a directory `/some/root/bin` with the commands you want to allow, and the chrooted program would see this directory as `/bin`. You'll need to copy everything needed for the execution of the program inside the chroot: libraries, data files, `bash`, the script itself, etc. The script might need `/proc` mounted inside the chroot; you can do this with a command like `mount -t proc proc /proc`.

  If you need to make a whole directory tree available to the script, say `/var/example`, you have several choices. You could make a copy under `/some/root`. You could make hard links (if they work for your application and the chroot is in the same filesystem). On Linux, you can do `mount --bind /var/example /some/root/var/example` to “graft” `/var/example` inside the chroot. Note that a symbolic link can't work since the target of the link is determined inside the chroot.

  Note that chroot doesn't provide absolute security, particularly against processes running as root. For example, a root process could create a device file inside the chroot and access the whole disk through it. A chrooted process can still make network connections (you can forbid this by not including any networking program inside the chroot *and* ensuring that the untrusted program cannot create a file and make it executable or overwrite an existing executable).

Comment: *You'll need to copy everything needed*, can I make symbolic or hard links rather than copy?

Comment: @kyb Hard link: yes. Symbolic link: no, a symbolic link can only point to a file that you can see, it doesn't let you escape a chroot. Hard links are hard to use for this and fiddly: they break if you replace the file, they expose the original copy in case it's writable inside the chroot. If you want to make a whole tree available, either copy it or do a read-only bind mount.

Comment: I need to make available common commands like `grep`, `awk`, `units`, etc. Do I need to copy every bin file and all dependancies manually or there is some handy hack to tell explicitly what utils should work in chroot?