# How to jail a process?

Tags: linux, bash, security, permissions, process

I am creating a tool which will run programs uploaded by my students and test their homeworks from programing class.

Their programs read from standard input, do some computations and then write to standard output. Nothing else. Each program consists of one executable file.

How do I prevent their programs from doing anything nasty on my system?

I would like to use linux.

EDIT: I do not trust neighter my students neighter my own server. There might be files with 777 permissions on my server that I do not want the students to read. I believe that I could use chroot command to prevent the access to files. But how can I prevent access for example to network and internet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run a bash script in a sort of sandbox?](http://superuser.com/questions/183794/is-it-possible-to-run-a-bash-script-in-a-sort-of-sandbox)

Comment: Basically you have a choice beween a chroot jail or a VM.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options, It's really a balance of time/effort vs how much you distrust your students.

The safest way would be to run a virtual linux machine, but is probably unnecessary if the machine's only purpose is a testbed.

With the right permissions on the rest of your files, you can just make a user "Student" and give them a single directory that they have permission for. They won't have permission to edit any system files and any potentially destructive tools like gparted will require sudo (Do not include them in sudoers).